# ¿Por qué "tener cara" es malo? ¿Y por qué "descarado" significa lo mismo, siendo exactamente lo contrario?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras, modismos

Me he dado cuenta de un fenómeno curioso: tanto ser "descarado" como "tener cara", "tener cara dura", "ser un caradura" o "tener mucha cara" tiene mala connotación. ¿Acaso todo lo relacionado con la "cara" implica algo malo?

Veamos el diccionario de la RAE:

> [**descarado**, da](http://dle.rae.es/descarado). (De descararse).
>
> 1. adj. Que habla u obra con desvergüenza, sin pudor ni respeto humano. U. t. c. s.
>
> [**descararse**](http://dle.rae.es/descararse) (De des- y cara).
>
> 1. prnl. Hablar u obrar con desvergüenza, descortés y atrevidamente o sin pudor.
>
> [**caradura**](http://dle.rae.es/caradura).
>
> 1. adj. Sinvergüenza, descarado. U. t. c. s.
>
> [**cara**](http://dle.rae.es/cara)<sup>1</sup>. (Del lat. cara)
>
> 10. f. coloq. desfachatez. *Fulano tiene mucha cara*, *Se necesita cara para hacer eso*.

Busco y no encuentro una explicación para este fenómeno. ¿Existe o es sólo casualidad? Mi conocimiento se inscribe a la variedad de España. ¿Es así en otros países?

Comment: Intuyo que tiene que ver con el uso irónico de "no tener" para expresar lo contrario.

Comment: Si aún te interesa, [des-](http://dle.rae.es/?id=CJuPwUn) como prefijo puede indicar tanto negación ("descontento") como **exceso** ("deslenguado" como tener mucha lengua; "desgastar" como gastar en exceso). "Descarado" significa, en efecto, *"tener demasiada cara"*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Según [etimologías de Chile](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?descaro) la relación de "cara" y "vergüenza" es que cuando haces algo que es causa de vergüenza se te pone la cara roja. `Desfachatez`, como indica la web, tiene un significado parecido, y está también formada por una palabra que alude a la cara o el aspecto.

Incluso las expresiones `ser un jeta` o `tener mucho morro`, que también aluden a la cara, parecen [tener origen](http://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/el-curioso-origen-etimologico-de-la-expresion-ser-un-jeta/) basado en connotaciones despectivas asociadas a la cara de, en este caso, un animal por motivos culturales.

Así que la mayoría de esas expresiones vienen a significar "si tuvieses decencia (vergüenza) se te pondría la cara roja con eso que has hecho". El que no parece arrepentido tiene entonces "mucha cara", o "no tiene cara" o tiene "la cara muy dura", etc.

Comment: Entonces no es que términos contradictorios apunten al mismo significado, sino que una expresión más larga acabó reduciéndose a "tener cara" o "ser caradura". Qué interesante, aprendí algo nuevo. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Puede decirse que todas estas expresiones se basan en que cierta persona puede hacer o decir tales cosas (mentiras, inmorales, insultivas, agraviantes, etc.) y no tener vergüenza, reparo, pudor o remordimiento.

En forma figurada, una persona normal al decir una mentira, por ejemplo, se pondría colorado, tendría gestos incómodos o ticks nerviosos. Alguien con **cara de piedra** puede hacerlo y no tener estos efectos. Piense en una piedra, que siempre se mantiene igual, inmutable. O **tener mucha cara** siendo algo similar, a esa persona no le importa en lo más mínimo lo que otras persona piensen de él por lo que hizo.

Expresiones comunes de este tipo pueden ser **"¿Cómo le da la cara para hacer eso?"**, **"Después de lo que me hizo ahora viene a pedirme un favor el muy caradura"**, **"Tiene la cara de piedra"**, **"Descaradamente se me insinuó en frente de mi pareja"**

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. De todos modos, mi pregunta iba más hacia el por qué términos contradictorios (tener cara / no tener) implican el mismo hecho.

Answer (score 1):

Ser un `caradura` significa no avergonzarte porque cuando uno está avergonzado, arrepentido, mintiendo, o hace algún mal a otra persona, lo normal es que no pueda mirar directamente a los ojos como cuando hablas normalmente, y si lo haces sin inmutarte, pues, tienes `la cara dura`.

El mismo origen para la palabra descarado, ¿Cómo puede ser que después de obrar de esa forma tan malévola aún te mire a los ojos, es un/una descarado/a? Porque, igual que en la otra expresión, cuando uno está avergonzado, arrepentido, mintiendo, o hace algún mal a otra persona, lo normal es que no pueda mirar directamente a los ojos y si has hecho algo malo y no te inmutas, debe ser porque no tienes cara, es decir, eres un `descarado`

En Perú también utilizamos las expresiones tiene `cara de palo` o `cara de jebe` o si prefieres, es un `cara de palo` o un `cara de jebe`.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. De todos modos, mi pregunta iba más hacia el por qué términos contradictorios (tener cara / no tener) implican el mismo hecho.